# client side validation in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following in my web.config...

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

... and I'm referencing jquery validation in my view...

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
```

... but validation is only occurring on the server.  What else do I need to do to get client side validation to work?  I thought that using the data annotations of [Required] on my model properties and then referencing the jquery validate files that it would then perform client side validation... but apparently there's more to it.

Comment: Do you mean its not telling you that its not valid? If so you could try adding: @Html.ValidationSummary() to your page and then it will display any errors.

Comment: Sorry, I already have @Html.ValidationSummary on the page.  It does tell me that I'm missing required fields but only after it hits the server for validation.  I'm trying to get the client side validation working so the form won't even submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use f12 in your chosen browser. And check the console for errors

Comment: How did I not think of that.  I had the validation scripts loaded above the jquery call.  Reversing that cleared it all up.  Thanks!